# Minimal Working Examples (MWEs) for LilyPond Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, lilypond, software

I recently answered [Unable to switch text fonts in LilyPond](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/47836/unable-to-switch-text-fonts-in-lilypond). In the question, the OP provided a link to his/her code, available [here](http://pastebin.com/zv8FXQxS). Visiting this link shows the code to be well over *400 lines long*. This means that a user who attempts to answer the question must be willing to sift through all of these lines of code searching for the problem. Indeed, in this example, the error was---guess where!---all the way down on line 423 :-)

I'm proposing a system wherein **we suggest the author reduce his/her LilyPond code to a minimal working example (MWE)**. Generally speaking, a minimal working example is *an example of **compilable** code that is as concise as possible, without any extraneous information, that still displays the problem at hand*. The above 400+ line example, for instance, could have been reduced to approximately 50 lines. This serves a few purposes:

1. It helps the author pinpoint *exactly* where the issue is.
2. In turn, this saves other users' time by preventing them from going on the "wild goose chase" hunting for errors on line 423.
3. Furthermore---and perhaps this is the most important!---*oftentimes the act of creating the MWE results in the user answering his/her own problem without having to ask it*.
4. Such lengthy code snippets can make it difficult for a user to concisely answer the problem in a post.
5. Lastly, this is regular practice elsewhere, including the various LilyPond listservs. Emphasizing MWEs here would put us on the same foot as the larger LilyPond community, allowing easier communication between "us" and "them" if the situation were to arise.

There are other positives to this, but these are the main five as I see it.

This is a common issue over at [LaTeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), and indeed their meta site has a famous [community wiki](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1) explaining exactly what a MWE is. Thankfully, LilyPond MWEs are (usually) nowhere near as complex as a TeX MWE, so we wouldn't need as complex a discussion as they do.

I'm not sure the best way to implement this; this is, of course, where the community comes in. If the solution is to draft an explanation of what an MWE with examples, I would be happy to create such a document.

I recognize that LilyPond questions are relatively rare on this site, but I hope the response isn't "the questions are rare, so we can just leave things as they are and deal with it." I worry that such a response could ultimately discourage other users from even trying to answer LilyPond questions.

Comment: Excellent idea, and as we hope we will get more Lilypond questions, this is very relevant. Would you be able to draft an initial community wiki post based off the LaTex one?

Comment: Absolutely; I'll try to roll it out within the next few days.

Comment: The code should also be housed here in case the link dies as then the question will be pretty useless. Most other sites that deal with code all the time have a similar policy.

Comment: This is sometimes called an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment, but the particular example isn't very good. The problem was simply that "something that should have been specified at the beginning of the file was specified at the end". Whether there were 4 or 40,000 lines of "stuff that looks like random music" in between should have been fairly irrelevant to diagnosing the problem, unless your debugging technique is "carefully examine each character in the file sequentially from the beginning to the end".